# The Classic jQuery Tabs with Bing Maps Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, bing-maps

I know that there are multiple issues with jQuery Tabs and using Maps.
And I have seen the multiple fixes and I am half-way there. But I have the most obscure issue and hoping that someone might understand why.

This is my code for the tabs

```
$("#contactTabs").tabs({ spinner: 'Loading <img src="../images/icons/ajax-loader.gif" />' });

$('#contactTabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
   if (ui.panel.id == "Map") {
   GetMap();
}
});
```

Which currently does not work.
But I was doing some testing and added in an ALERT() to see if the "GetMap()" was even attempting to be loaded... so this was the code that I tested with, and it works just fine.

```
$("#contactTabs").tabs({ spinner: 'Loading <img src="../images/icons/ajax-loader.gif" />' });

$('#contactTabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
   if (ui.panel.id == "Map") {
   alert("load map");
   GetMap();
}
});
```

So I haven't a clue why adding the ALERT() causes the map to load and removing the ALERT just doesn't load the map at all.

Is there any clarification that someone can give me on this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the GetMap() function inside of the following.

```
setTimeout(
  function(){
     GetMap();
  }, 1000);
```

What's probably happening is since JavaScript executes a lot of code asynchronously, GetMap() is being called before the data has actually been loaded completely.

The sample assumes the data will load within 1 second. Good practice, however, would be to check that the requested data has been fully loaded before calling GetMap().